# Scala - can unapply return varargs?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, unapply

Object `L1` below works.  I can "create" an `L1` by passing in varargs, which is nice, but I would like to be able to assign to an `L1` using the same syntax. Unfortunately, the way I've done it here requires the uglier syntax of nesting an `Array` inside the `L1`.

```
object L1 {
    def apply(stuff: String*) = stuff.mkString(",")
    def unapply(s: String) = Some(s.split(","))
}
val x1 = L1("1", "2", "3")
val L1(Array(a, b, c)) = x1
println("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s".format(a,b,c))
```

I attempted accomplish this in what seems like an obvious way, as in `L2` below:

```
object L2 {
    def apply(stuff: String*) = stuff.mkString(",")
    def unapply(s: String) = Some(s.split(","):_*)
}
val x2 = L2("4", "5", "6")
val L2(d,e,f) = x2
println("d=%s, e=%s, f=%s".format(d,e,f))
```

But this give the error:

```
error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here 
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)`.
```

Is it possible for `unapply` to use varargs in this way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think what you want is unapplySeq.  Jesse Eichar has a nice write up on [unapplySeq](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/extract-sequences-unapplyseq.html)

```
scala> object L2 {
     |     def unapplySeq(s: String) : Option[List[String]] = Some(s.split(",").toList)
     |     def apply(stuff: String*) = stuff.mkString(",")
     | }
defined module L2

scala> val x2 = L2("4", "5", "6")
x2: String = 4,5,6

scala> val L2(d,e,f) = x2
d: String = 4
e: String = 5
f: String = 6
```